# Why mongodb-community does not start?

Tags: mongodb, macos

I see this in terminal:

```
kukodajanos@Kukodas-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew services list                      
Name              Status      User File
mongodb-community error  3584 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

Once I installed like this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

And started like this:

```
brew services start mongodb-community@6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello to fix this first stop current MongoDB

`brew services stop mongodb-community@6.0`

Then run with sudo

`sudo brew services start mongodb-community@6.0`

Hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: I tried, this did no work, but then I stopped, uninstalled, installed again. That helped.